# class not removing as expected with click counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var clickCount = 0;

$(".arrowRight").click(function () {
    clickCount++;

    if (clickCount >= 3) {
        clickCount = 0;
        $(".arrowRight").removeClass("active");
        $(".arrowRight").addClass("disable");
    }
    else { 
        $(".arrowRight").removeClass("disable"); // this is the line that isnt working
        $(".arrowRight").addClass("active"); // but this works
    }
});
```

Everything works with the above up until my '`disable`' class. It adds after the 3 clicks, but the idea is the clicks reset after the 3rd as well, hints the `else` and even the '`active`' gets added correctly (*eg.* within the else after 3rd click resets -- **but the `disable` class will not remove!**

```
.disable { 
       pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: could you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changes required from css

remove this line from css class

```
pointer-events: none;
```

so class will be

```
.disable {
   cursor: default;
}
```

here is example JSFIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/stt2632m/